# How to call function after ajax content fully loaded like $(window).load() or window.onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax but is there any option to call function after ajax content fully loaded like `$(window).load()` or `window.onload`? When i'm in fresh page everything working fine with `$(window).load()` or `window.onload` function because some scripts work after window complete load. But the problem is in ajax and when i click on a link and page is dynamically load contents from another page so we don't need `$(window).load()` or `window.onload` function but because some script only work when window loaded or content fully loaded so how to call function after ajax content fully loaded like `$(window).load()` or `window.onload` ?

```
function windowload() {
      //Some functions works only after window load
 };



$(function() {

   $(window).on('load', windowload);

        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var $this = this.href;

                        $.ajax({
                        url: '' + $this + '',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(html) {
                        var div = $('#style', $(html));
                        $('#style').html(div);

                        //call windowload but not working
                         windowload();

                        //Also tried this but not working
                        $('#style').on('load', function(){
                            windowload();
                           //Some functions work only after ajax content fully loaded 

                             });

                      });
               });
```

**Edit :**
I need a function after ajax content fully loaded not after ajax request complete.

Comment: you need to read more about load and ready events, start here - > https://api.jquery.com/load-event/. P.S downvote for not making sense

Comment: Sorry i don't want `.load()`

Comment: hm or you want code which needs to run after the ajax is finished but not before the load event, in this case Rory's suggestion is not going to work, you can just replace this $(function() { with $(window).load( and execute your ajax after the load event  (upvote :) if you describe your problem more clearly )

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: OK, upvoted, well did you try my suggestion then, it shold work just your ajax will hold a little bit longer and then all code will be executed once the event fires

Comment: Yes i tried your suggestion but not working. :(

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to find the solution to this exact same problem for hours. What worked for me was

```
$(document).ajaxComplete()
```

I put my code in there and when Ajax was complete and the content of the div fully reloaded, I added the style I wanted to add. Hope this helps someone. Calling the method from ajax success won't work.

Comment: I had to execute a code on complete ajax load after the click of a button. This function did it for me.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you need to call a single function at multiple points in the pages lifecycle (as you describe above, where the logic is needed on both page load and also when an AJAX request completes), then you can extract the required logic to its own function to be called as needed. Try this:

```
function htmlLoaded() {
    // Some functions work only after window load 
}

$(window).load(htmlLoaded); // called on page load

$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {
                var styleHtml = $(html).find('#style');
                $('#style').html(styleHtml);
                htmlLoaded(); // called after the AJAX request completes successfully
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Also note that I made a couple of amendments to improve the logic in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Style").ready(function(){
   console.log('Style is fully loaded.');
   windowload();
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: The question is about running `window loading` code after `#style` loading.

Comment: @ClementNerma, This code `$("#Style").ready()` will triggers right after `#style` content is loaded !

Comment: Yes but you don't run the `windowload` function, the console.log() will just show a message. (but I just understood one interesting thing about .ready thanks :))

Answer (score -2):

When you call a function you must use the `()` symbol like `windowload()`.
Here is the fixed, well-indented code : (I removed the empty quotes, useless here)

```
function windowload() {
  //Some functions works only after window load
};

$(function() {
  $(window).on('load', windowload);

  $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = this.href;

    $.ajax({
      url: $this, // Removed the empty quotes which are useless here
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(html) {
        var div = $('#style', $(html));
        $('#style').html(div.html());
        $('#style').ready(windowload);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

By adding a new `script` tag which will run the `windowload()` function, we solve the problem. Because when this script is runned all HTML content placed before this tag has been loaded.

Comment: You want to call the `windowload`function after ajax request is complete or after the `$('#style')` load is finished ?

Comment: After `$('#style')` fully loaded.

Comment: I've edited a few second ago please try again I did an error

Comment: I tried but not working. Now ajax totally stop working.

Comment: Sorry I did an error with content type. Please try a new time

Comment: You have to place the code you want to run into the `contentLoaded`. Here if you want to run `windowload` try the code I've edited. If that doesn't work I won't able to help you I think...

Comment: Please see when i add `+ "<script></script>"` tag, the ajax stop working but after adding `+ "<div></div>"` it working.

Comment: if you add the `+ "<div></div>"` is `windowload` runned ?

Comment: No no i just tried that why `+ "<script></script>"` tag not working. But working when i add `+ "<div></div>"` .

Comment: I don't understand at all... If the `script` tag works the `windowload` function must be runned !

Comment: You also try and see when you add  `$('#style').html(div.html() + '<script type="text/javascript"></script>');` then total ajax stop working.

Comment: Yeah but when you add `+ "<div></div>"` you say the `script` tag works so the `windowload` function works too ?

Comment: No i not say `windowload` working. I say that when you add `$('#style').html(div.html() + '<script type="text/javascript"></script>');` then ajax stop working and when you add `$('#style').html(div.html() + '<div></div>');` then ajax working.

Comment: That's really strange... I don't know how to fix it, sorry.

Comment: `$('#style').ready(windowload;)` syntax error :) replace with `$('#style').ready(windowload);`